# Using a defined set of controls for many regressions in R

Tags: r, lm

I'm running a bunch of regressions; they differ mainly in the dependent variable, but also in a few independent variables.

However, all have a common set of controls, so I'd like to be able to call something like (heuristically):

```
lm(y~x_idiosyncratic+common_controls,data=data)
```

What is the best way to do this in R?

It was pretty easy in Stata, *a la*:

```
local myx "x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10"
regress y `myx'
```

Here's what I've come up with (inspired by the ?formula page), but it looks a bit clunky; is there something cleaner somebody knows of?

```
controls<-paste(paste0("z",1:30),collapse="+")

idiosyncratic1<-paste(paste0("x",1:10),collapse="+")
reg1<-lm(as.formula(paste0("y1~",idiosyncratic1,controls)),data=data)

idiosyncratic2<-paste(paste0("xx",1:10),collapse="+")
reg2<-lm(as.formula(paste0("y2~",idiosyncratic2,controls)),data=data)
```

and so on.

This will also be helpful for running robustness checks--one can simply redefine the set of controls:

```
controls2<-paste(paste0("zz",1:20),collapse="+")
```

So I'd like a way to do this as cleanly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want the `update` command.  It allows you to add/drop terms from a formula easily.

```
head(mtcars) # using mtcars for the example
# Create your common controls in a formula
common <-  ~ cyl + hp + drat
# Add the response and an additional predictor
new_form <- update(common, mpg ~ . + wt)
# Run the regression
reg <- lm(new_form, data = mtcars)
```

Comment: Nice! I thought update could only be used to `lm` objects--good to know it can be applied to formulas. One more thing--it may be good to wrap the assignment to `common` in parentheses--for a larger set of controls that runs onto the next line, this is needed to execute it properly. Also perhaps mention the `?update.formula` help page

Comment: @MichaelChirico You don't need the parenthesis to wrap. You just need to end the current line with a `+` to let the interpreter know there is more to come.  I rejected your edit since `other_vars` isn't defined in mtcars and would make the example not runnable as is.